# Science fiction horror novella about yellow smoke that can control people's minds

Tags: story-identification, horror, soft-sci-fi, novella

It was a sci-fi and horror novella (the book contained 3 stories in total). The protagonist was a young kid with asthma. His parents were scientists and had to move to a new town in the middle of nowhere when they got a new job. There he finds everyone had a yellow tint in their eyes. He uncovers a plot that the smoke they are making there was controlling everyone's minds. Slowly his parents get controlled too. Only he escapes because his inhaler counteracts the smoke. There was also a girl who was safe.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: I do not remember the publication date but it was in school library and I read it in in 2011.